# How to iteratively train forecast models (GAM, MARS, ...) based on selected days and calculate the variable importance in the time period

Tags: r, time-series, iteration, prediction, forecasting

I have a data table which always have different number of columns and column names and a numeric variable called `days` (this variable also differs; now/here: 50):

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)

days -> 50  
## Create random data table: ##
dt.train <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                       "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                       "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)
```

I'm modelling/training a Linear Model (= LM), where I want to predict the DE column and I calculate the variable importance with respect to the `days` variable. See the following code snippet:

```
## MODEL FITTING: ##
## Linear Model: ##

## Function that calculates the iteratively prediction: ##
calcPred <- function(data){
  ## Model fitting: ##
  xgbModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)
  ## Model training: ##
  stats::predict.lm(xgbModel, data)
}

## Function that calculates the iteratively variable importance: ##
varImportance <- function(data){
  ## Model fitting: ##
  xgbModel <- stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)
  
  terms <- attr(xgbModel$terms , "term.labels")
  varimp <- caret::varImp(xgbModel)
  importance <- data[, .(date, imp = t(varimp))]
} 


## Train Data PREDICTION with iteratively xgbModel: ##
dt.train <- dt.train[, c('prediction') := calcPred(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt.train)) %/% days]

## Iteratively variable importance:##
dt.importance <- data.table::copy(dt.train[, c("prediction") := NULL])
dt.importance <- dt.importance[, varImportance(.SD), by = seq_len(nrow(dt.train)) %/% days]
```

What happens here: My model is always trained for 50 days and then precisely for this time period there is a prediction of these trained 50 days done. And that continues until the end date of my table. In addition, the `varImportance()` function gives the variable importances of the predictors (all columns, excluding `date` and `DE`) in the training intervall (here for each 50 days).

Originally I thought that I could use the functions `calcPred()` and `varImportance()` for a Generalized Additive Model (= GAM) and Multivariative Adaptive Regression Spline (= MARS) or Gradient Boosting (= GB) too, but unfortunately this versions only work with the LM.

I would now like to briefly describe the model fitting for the other three models in general, but I would also need your help here so that in the end the GAM, MARS and GB model as well as the LM are calculated.

**GAM:**

```
## Create data-vector with dates of dt.train: ##
v.trainDate <- dt.train$date
## Delete column "date" of train data for model fitting: ##
dt.train <- dt.train[, c("date") := NULL]

## Preparation for GAM: ##
trainDataNames <- names(dt.train)
responseVar <- trainDataNames[1]
trainDataNames <- trainDataNames[trainDataNames != responseVar]
## Create right-hand side of GAM model in string/character format: ##
formulaRight <- paste('s(', trainDataNames, ')', sep = '', collapse = ' + ')
## Create the whole formula for GAM model in string/character format: ##
formulaGAM <- paste(responseVar, '~', formulaRight, collapse = ' ')
## Coerce to a formula object: ##
formulaGAM <- as.formula(formulaGAM)

## MODEL FITTING: ##
## Generalized Additive Model: ##
xgbModel <- mgcv::gam(formulaGAM, data = dt.train)

## Train and Test Data PREDICTION with xgbModel: ##
dt.train$prediction <- mgcv::predict.gam(xgbModel, dt.train)

## Add date columns to dt.train and dt.test: ##
dt.train <- data.table(date = v.trainDate, dt.train)
```

**MARS:**

```
## Create vectors with all DE values of train data set: ##
v.trainY <- dt.train$DE
## Save dates of train data in an extra vector: ##
v.trainDate <- dt.train$date
## Create train matrices for GB model fitting: ##
m.trainData <- as.matrix(dt.train[, c("date", "DE") := list(NULL, NULL)])
## Model fitting with grid-search: ##: ##
hyper_grid <- expand.grid(degree = 1:3, 
                          nprune = seq(2, 100, length.out = 10) %>% floor()
              )
              
## MODEL FITTING: ##
## Multivariate Adaptive Regression Spline: ##
xgbModel <- caret::train(x = m.trainData, 
                         y = v.trainY,
                         method = "earth",
                         metric = "RMSE",
                         trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
                                       tuneGrid = hyper_grid
              )
              
              
## Train Data PREDICTION with xgbModel: ##
dt.train$prediction <- stats::predict(xgbModel, dt.train)
```

**GB:**

```
## Create vectors with all DE values of train data set: ##
v.trainY <- dt.train$DE
## Save dates of train data in an extra vector: ##
v.trainDate <- dt.train$date
## Create train matrices for GB model fitting: ##
m.trainData <- as.matrix(dt.train[, c("date", "DE") := list(NULL, NULL)])

## Gradient Boosting with hyper parameter tuning: ##
xgb_trcontrol <- caret::trainControl(method = "cv",
                                     number = 3,
                                     allowParallel = TRUE,
                                     verboseIter = TRUE,
                                     returnData = FALSE
)

xgbgrid <- base::expand.grid(nrounds = c(15000), # 15000
                             max_depth = c(2),
                             eta = c(0.01),
                             gamma = c(1),
                             colsample_bytree = c(1),
                             min_child_weight = c(2),
                             subsample = c(0.6)
)

## MODEL FITTING: ##
## Gradient Boosting: ##
xgbModel <- caret::train(x = m.trainData, 
                         y = v.trainY,
                         trControl = xgb_trcontrol,
                         tuneGrid = xgbgrid,
                         method = "xgbTree"
)

## Train data PREDICTION with xgbModel: ##
dt.train$prediction <- stats::predict(xgbModel, m.trainData)

## Add DE and date columns to dt.train: ##
dt.train <- data.table(DE = v.trainY, dt.train)
dt.train <- data.table(date = v.trainDate, dt.train)
```

**How do I calculate the same for the other three models as for the LM?** I hope someone can help me.
I'm sorry the question got so long.

Answer (score 1):

You could define the model as a function you pass as argument to `calcPred` and `varImportance`.

For example with a `LM`

```
model <- function(data) {stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)}
```

With `GAM`

```
model <- function(data) {mgcv::gam(formulaGAM, data = data)}
```

with `MARS`:

```
model <- function(data) {
  hyper_grid <- expand.grid(degree = 1:3, 
                            nprune = seq(2, 100, length.out = 10) %>% floor())
  caret::train(x = subset(data, select = -DE),
               y = data$DE,
               method = "earth",
               metric = "RMSE",
               trControl = trainControl(method = "cv", number = 10),
               tuneGrid = hyper_grid)
}
```

I updated the code to take into account this new argument:

```
library(data.table)
library(caret)
library(magrittr)


days <- 50
## Create random data table: ##
dt.train <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 366),
                       "DE" = rnorm(366, 35, 1), "Wind" = rnorm(366, 5000, 2), "Solar" = rnorm(366, 3, 2),
                       "Nuclear" = rnorm(366, 100, 5), "ResLoad" = rnorm(366, 200, 3),  check.names = FALSE)

dt.importance <- data.table::copy(dt.train)

## Define model & prediction functions ##

model <- function(data) {stats::lm(DE ~ .-1-date, data = data)}

predict <- function(data,model) {stats::predict(model, data)}

calcPred <- function(data,model){
  if (nrow(data)==days) {
  stats::predict(model,data) } else {
  NULL }
}

## Function that calculates the iteratively variable importance: ##
varImportance <- function(data,model){
  cat(nrow(data),'\n')
  if (nrow(data)==days) {
  terms <- attr(model$terms , "term.labels")
  varimp <- caret::varImp(model)
  importance <- data[, .(date, imp = t(varimp))]} else
  { NULL }
}


## Train Data PREDICTION with iteratively xgbModel: ##
dt.train <- dt.train[, c('prediction') := calcPred(.SD,model(.SD)), by = (seq_len(nrow(dt.train))-1) %/% days]

## Iteratively variable importance:##

dt.importance <- dt.importance[, varImportance(.SD,model(.SD)), by = (seq_len(nrow(dt.train))-1) %/% days]
```

To use the other models, just use the model function you wish in the above code.
This works with `LM` or `GAM` on the dataset you provided.

Unfortunately, `varImp` seems not to work on your dataset with `MARS` although this [seems feasible](https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html).

Comment: I have already tried something like this, but when using your coding and the ```calcPred()``` for GAM and MARS I get the following error messages. Error for GAM is: ```Model has more coefficients than data```. Error for MARS: ```In nominalTrainWorkflow(x = x, y = y, wts = weights, info = trainInfo,  : There were missing values in resampled performance measures.``` The variable importance doesn't work for GAM and MARS. Does your code work, when you are running it?

Comment: You're right, I did it too quickly and varImp currently doesn't work for MARS although it should : https://topepo.github.io/caret/variable-importance.html. I try to solve this and come back to you

Comment: It also doesn't work for the GAM, in my case! The ```varImp()``` doesn't work for the LM, when I'm having more than 12 predictors, which is a little bit weird. The thrown error is than: ```j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group data table R```. Do you know why this happen?

Comment: Thank you so much, for you help!!

Comment: The above code now works with `GAM` : the errors came from the last chunck which doesn't have enough rows (16 instead of 50)

Comment: Thank you, now the error doesn't appear any more. But now the last 16 rows are not predicted. Why can't we just iterate every 50 days and then take the remaining days (in my case the last 16 days) that are left over and calculate a prediction and variable importance for these last remaining days?

Comment: This seems linked to the way the model is calculated. For example `caret::varImp(model(dt.train[321:366]))` works, but `caret::varImp(model(dt.train[322:366]))` doesn't. So 45/46 data points seem to be needed (see `caret::varImp(model(dt.train[1:45]))`), probably linked to the formula used. You could use `frollaply` over more than 46 points to get prediction for the last points. It would be longer to use it on the whole dataset.

Comment: Oh okay, When I have other columns for the data table ```dt.train```, and I use the LM I get for the ```calcPred()``` the following error: ```In predict.lm(model, data) :
  prediction from a rank-deficient fit may be misleading```. And always when I get this error through the prediction, I get the error for the ```varImpt()```:  ```j doesn't evaluate to the same number of columns for each group data table R```. Why is this the case?

Comment: When using the ```rollapply()``` function the same error messages happens. Prediction works, but I also get the warning message with ```rank-deficient fit``` as I mentioned before, and the ```varImp()``` doens't work anyway

Comment: Is this on the data you provided or on other data? Each model has its particularities, and checking that it fits to your data in all circumstances can be tedious.

Comment: This is to a data with other predictors. I have in total 87 possible predictors, but I don't want to fit my model always on the same, so I differ the predictors a little bit. Could this error message happens because of multicollinearity?

Comment: This is what I thought, multicolinearities could well be a cause.

Comment: This would mean, that I need to use Ridge, Lasso or Elastic Net Regression?

Comment: Difficult to tell without the actual data. As usual, data science is 80% tedious hard work of data preparation & choosing the right models ;-)

Comment: Yes that's tricky. Unfortunately, the ```varImp()``` doesn't work for the MARS model at the moment.

Comment: Yes, this is what I stil wanted to add to my answer : it should work according to doc, but it doesn't...